# How to get odd/even display in a table for groups of rows?

Tags: php

I have a MySQL query that returns user data in PHP and I have this code for odd/even rows:

```
$num = 0;
$class = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $class = "odd";
    if($num % 2 == 0){
        $class = "even";
    }
    $num++;
}
```

How could I do this to make an even/odd display for a group of rows. For example, I'm returning this data:
ID/NAME/PRODUCT

```
1/John/Car
1/John/Bike
2/Mike/Apple
3/Alex/Boat
3/Alex/House
3/Alex/Bicycle
```

And all rows with ID 1 should be odd, all with ID 2 should be even, all with ID 3 should be odd, and so on?

Comment: is this requirement for CSS/styling reasons or other? Incidentally: the `mysql` api was deprecated years ago and remove from PHP 7+ so you ought to consider learning `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: It's for CSS/styling... I have more entries for same IDs in a 5k+ table and this would make it easier to follow. Also, sorry, wrote that code example fast and didn't put the i in mysql (but I'm using mysqli everywhere).

Comment: What do you have in mind as an output?

Comment: to style odd / even rows you can use just CSS rules - `nth-child` selectors etc or `nth-of-type( odd ){}` and `nth-of-type(even){}`

Comment: @Andreas - I just want to output the class name for each group of rows.

Comment: @RamRaider - yeah, I know about that, but I don't think I could apply it to groups of rows like what I need - I need to style first group of rows with same id odd, second group of rows with same different id even and so on.

Comment: What you want is a very basic, one-level control break … https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break

Answer (score 1):

You miss this line `$num=$row['ID'];`
Add In your code then it will work fine.
Below is the updated code:

```
$num = 0;
$class = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $num=$row['ID'];
    $class = "odd";
    if($num % 2 == 0){
        $class = "even";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you keep `$num = 0;` and `$num++;`?

Comment: $num++ not needed

Comment: This sort-of works... I mean it does add odd/even based on ID, but also based on the number... And mind that since this is a DB query, not all numbers are in available as IDs (some may be removed)... so if I have 10/11/13/14 it will make 10 even, 11/13 odd and 14 even, but I need them to be 10 even 11 odd 13 even 14 odd in this example.

Comment: Basically first group of IDs should be odd, second even, third odd and so on, but regardless of the numerical value/representation of the ID since IDs may not be in exact order in places.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the last id to see if you're on the same one or not. If you are on a different id then toggle the class.

```
$last_id = 0;
$class = "even";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  if($last_id !== $row['ID']){
    $class = ($class === "even")? "odd": "even";
    $last_id = $row['ID'];
  }
  // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Still not getting the right results, I get this:
1005 (even)
1005 (even)
1005 (odd)
1005 (odd)
1006 (even)
1008 (even)
1008 (odd)
...

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use an array to store the `row id` you could then use the size of the array in the modulus

```
$ids=[];
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    $id=$row['ID'];
    if( !in_array( $id, $ids ) ) $ids[]=$id;
    $class = count( $ids ) % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
}
```

Curious that your results are out of kilter like that. A little demo to emulate how I imagined this to work. As I cannot test your database data a simple array of id-like integers should suffice. For clarity I added spaces between groups

```
$rs=[23,23,23, 24,24,24, 25,26,27,28,29, 30,30,30,30,30, 33,35,66, 89,89];
$ids=[];


foreach( $rs as $id ){
    if( !in_array( $id, $ids ) ) $ids[]=$id;
    $class = count( $ids ) % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';

    printf( '%d - %s<br />', $id, $class );
}
```

and this will output:

```
23 - odd
23 - odd
23 - odd

24 - even
24 - even
24 - even

25 - odd
26 - even
27 - odd
28 - even
29 - odd

30 - even
30 - even
30 - even
30 - even
30 - even

33 - odd
35 - even
66 - odd

89 - even
89 - even
```

The output seems to follow the odd/even rules without the anomalies you mention...

Comment: Still not getting the right results, I get this:
1005 (even)
1005 (even)
1005 (even)
1005 (odd)
1006 (odd)
1008 (even)
1008 (odd)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but this wasn't mandatory so to say and I've kinda given up on it, but I'm still curious as to why I'm not getting the right result... And yeah, I couldn't give access to the DB as it's with personal info... But here's a screenshot, I've just added a class to even rows (<tr>) to highlight them for easy viewing... as you can see, it's not right. And I'm thinking regardless of the DB, if the IDs are numerical, it should work right, right? SS: https://i.imgur.com/nlTmt4i.png